# Join two string lists elements one by one

Tags: c#, string, linq, ienumerable

I have two `IEnumerable<string>` that I need to combine joining their elements "index by index".

At the moment I'm using a simple `foreach` statement to merge the elements one by one and add them to a `List<string>`.

```
List<string> res = new List<string>();
int index = 0;
foreach (var date in dates)
    res.Add(
        string.Join(
            ",", 
            DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(date)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), 
            values.ElementAt(index++)
            )
        );
```

I was wondering if there is a way to solve this directly in LINQ.

Comment: [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0).

Comment: That was unexpectedly easy and fast. Thanks man.